# Log user in to drupal remotely with service

Tags: php, web-services, session, drupal

I am trying to get a user to login to drupal using an existing service. I am able to POST the username and password to drupal on the remote server and I do get authentication information back.

My problem is how do I register the session so drupal knows I am logged in? Once I login, and try to access anything, I get `"Access denied for anonymous user"`.

I noticed looking at the services notes that is says:

`Authentication : header Cookie must be set to <session_name>=<sessid> given by the login response of a successful login`

so I tried

```
$_SESSION[$curlResult->session_name] = $curlResult->sessid;
```

which I don't think is what that line above is saying. Not sure what a header cookie is.

`$curlResult->session_name` and  `$curlResult->sessid` are definitely valid and that is part of what is returned on successful login.

Comment: I think I just figured it out. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "" . $_SESSION['user']->session_name . "=" . $_SESSION['user']->sessid . "");`

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us an idea of what you're trying to do once logged in as a user?
There is the Services module which can allow for user access through REST.

I've had success logging in as a remote user, without Services module, using Python mechanize for load testing.

Comment: I gather a presentation list associated with whoever is logged in. I have it working now though. I query a json file which returns the data. I cant use just ajax to call the json file because I get a cross domain issue. Using cURL solved my problem except once logged in, I wasn't able to use the other services that require you to be logged in, but like I said, I figured it out